# mac boot, and windows storage on same USB

Tags: windows, macos, usb, partitioning

I have a 64GB usb to install mac OS X on, but it will not use the whole drive so I would like to partition it. I want the other partition to be accessible from pc and mac. To install mac I need to use the 'OS Extended (Journaled)' format, and it isn't compatible with windows.
I have tried formating it as the mac compatible file system and then adding a fat partition, but windows says I need to format the drive before it can be used.
In Disk Management it says that everything is 'Healthy' but there is lots of unallocated space.
[image]
Is there a way to create my fantasy?
pun:

> or will I have to fill by ***bath*** with orange soda instead?!

mark up if you hate the pun 
of not

Answer (score 0):

Format your USB drive for **exFAT**. That is compatible with both operating systems. Of course you'll lose some of features from each OS but you'll have the availability in either OS that you are looking for.

Comment: I highly suggest exFAT over FAT32, for less restrictions, especially on file size.